# Evaluating While Loops inside Modules

Tags: function-construction, scoping

I am trying to compute some objects inside while loops within modules, but I keep getting the following error:

```
Set::write: "Tag Times in <blah> Null is Protected."
```

I have made this minimal example to illustrate what I want to do - sum each output of a while loop then output the final sum:

```
f[x_] := Module[{n = 1, m = 1, output = 0, y, z},
  While[m < 5,
    While[n < 5,
       y = x^(m + n) z^m;
       n++;
       ]
      output = y + output;
    m++;
    ]
   output
  ]

f[5]
```

In my mind this should produce a Polynomial in z. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I suspect you get an error due to `z`  not being defined and you don't solve for it in your code. This is why you get an error

Comment: You have missing semicolons after `While` loops.

Comment: You need ; after your closing braces for the Whiles.  Without these your are multiplying `output` by the While blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you are not suppressing the output of the `While` statements with a semicolon.

However, you still will not get the result you are expecting because you have scoped `z` inside of `Module` and your `output` will return a variable that is no longer in scope (a `Unique` variable from the `Module`).

An example of a *Wolfram Language* way of coding this is:

```
f[x_] = Total@Flatten@Table[x^(m + n) z^m, {m, 4}, {n, 4}];
```

This is a case where using `Set` (`=`) instead of `SetDelayed` (`:=`) makes the code faster.

Now you will get the results you expect.

```
f[1]
```

> 4 z + 4 z^2 + 4 z^3 + 4 z^4

Hope this helps.

---

**Update** OP's loops are to 4 not 5. Have updated for this.

Comment: I think `f[1]` should be `z + z^2 + z^3 + z^4`

Comment: @m_goldberg It is 5 by 5 not 5 by 1.

Comment: The OP's while-loops loop from 1 to 4 in both loops.

Comment: @m_goldberg Yes. That is correct. 4 by 4. Not 4 by 1 as you suggested. But not 5 by 5 as I originally read it.  I`ll update.

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two errors in your code: misplaced semicolons and not initializing `n` at the right point of the code. Also, I think it would good if you allowed the free variable to passed to `f`, rather than hard wiring it into `f`.

```
f[x_?NumericQ, z_Symbol] :=
  Module[{n, m = 1, output = 0, y},
    While[m < 5,
      n = 1;
      While[n < 5, y = x^(m + n) z^m; n++];
      output = y + output;
      m++];
    output]
```

With this

```
f[1, x]
```

> `x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4`

and

```
f[5, z]
```

> `3125 z + 15625 z^2 + 78125 z^3 + 390625 z^4`